# How to get reference user UIDs as a parent from firebase database? #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image: This is my database in firebase]

```
DatabaseReference myDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

private FirebaseAuth authData;
private EditText number;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_schedule);

    number= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);

    DatabaseReference lastdata=myDatabase.child("QExqazU73kTJllMFtsN0alwH6aq1").child("Schedule").child("Monday").child("Hour");

    lastdata.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            String text= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            number.setText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

In this part:

```
DatabaseReference lastdata=myDatabase.child("QExqazU73kTJllMFtsN0alwH6aq1").child("Schedule").child("Monday").child("Hour");
```

If I write user uid like that results are true. However, I want to get user uid which is belongs to users who are logged in.

If I write

```
String user_id= authData.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference userid_database=myDatabase.child(user_id).child("Schedule").child("Monday").child("Hour");
```

like that, program close and don't run again.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the exception with which your program closes it's hard to be sure. But one likely problem is that the user isn't signed in yet when you try to read their data, which would lead to a `NullPointerException` when trying to call `getUid()`.

The solution for that problem would be to wait until the user is authenticated:

```
 myAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            System.out.println("onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            String user_id= user.getUid();
            DatabaseReference userid_database=myDatabase.child(user_id).child("Schedule").child("Monday").child("Hour");
           ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It didn't run. It said " 'TAG' has private access in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity' ". I tried to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity and add  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0' in build.gradle file but it didn't work.

Comment: TAG is just a common name for the constant you pass into `Log` calls. I replaced it with a regular `System.out.println()` now, since it has nothing to do with Firebase.

Comment: I am new at Android and also not good at Java. Now it said in debug:                   caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot write " myAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
" at the beginning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your login activity

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
AuthData authData = mDatabase.getAuth();
  if(authData!=null){
  //Get uid of logged in user
  uid = authData.getUid() ;
  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "-"+authData.getAuth().get("email"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}
```